# Microsoft Azure speech-to-text in Brazilian Portuguese

Tags: azure, speech-to-text

I'm on a project that needs to communicate with clients automatically, so I'm listing several possibilities for communicating using speech-to-text and text-to-speech APIs, but seeing the documentation for one of the top cloud platforms , Microsoft Azure, it was not clear whether the speech to text service has features in the Portuguese language of Brazil (pt-br). My intention is to pass an audio to the "speech to text" service so that it returns, in Brazilian Portuguese, a text with what was spoken, and on the website (image below) it appears that the service only provides to train the model of Microsoft Azure to support the Portuguese language, and there is no link that explicitly states that the "speech to text" feature is enabled and works for the Portuguese language.

[image: Microsoft Azure]

Anyone who has ever tested this API would be able to tell me about this service?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement but I guess Brazilian Portuguese is not supported by Azure Speech to Text API.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speech/